# Heroku app not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I wanted to reseed the database of my Heroku app. I ran: `heroku run rake db:migrate` and then `heroku run rake db:seed`. I navigated to the app and I saw the changes were successful. 
Then, I changed one of the views and re-migrated and seeded it and ran `git push heroku master`.

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

Recent Heroku logs show that I was trying to grab a user by an ID that no user had, but I've removed this code since then. I've tried deploying from another branch and doing a rollback, nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: I copied the folder, ran `git init`, and then renamed the app to something else. Not really an ideal solution, but it works.

Comment: Have you tried using PGAdmin or some equivalent to look into your Heroku database? That always helps me troubleshoot this stuff.

Comment: Connecting in PGAdmin worked. Permission denied, but the connection's there.

Comment: If you only change views, then you need not `migrate your database` again or `seed it` again. The main purpose to run `rake db:migrate` is if you create a migration to change your current schema. And once you run `rake db:seed`, there is no need to do it again, unless you destroy those columns from the database. You need not run it everytime you run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Make sure you're entering the Heroku credentials: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku

Comment: This is an application error not a platform error - check `heroku logs` and it should be obvious what the problem is. Also, if you migrate you need to restart.